# SQL query to find out Display employee name as well as their age and experience in years

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

SQL query to find out  Display employee name as well as their age and experience in years.

```
SELECT 
   ENAME,

   CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOJ, GETDATE())/12) +' years '+
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOJ, GETDATE()) % 12)+ ' months' 
   AS AgeInYears, 

   CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, GETDATE())/12) +' years '+
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, GETDATE()) % 12)+ ' months' 
   AS EXPERIENCEInYears

FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a question?  I fixed the database tags.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

Your field name was wrong.  I change DOJ to DOB.

```
SELECT 
   ENAME,

   CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE())/12) +' years '+
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE()) % 12)+ ' months' 
   AS AgeInYears, 

   CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, GETDATE())/12) +' years '+
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEDIFF(MONTH, hiredate, GETDATE()) % 12)+ ' months' 
   AS EXPERIENCEInYears

FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Comment: Still i am getting Error 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: SELECT ENAME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE())/12) +' years '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(3),DATEDIFF(MONTH, DOB, GETDATE())/12) +' years '+
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(2)' at line 3

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec